# Ubuntu PHPMYADMIN ''No such file or directory &mdash" error

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

My phpmyadmin with mysql worked perfectly for 2 months, and now  I am getting this problem (i did absolutely nothing, I'm not sure why I get it).

```
No such file or directory &mdash; The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

I'm trying to run a js script that connects to ''localhost''. I've tried changing `config.inc.php` ''localhost'' to 127.0.0.1 but i still get the same error. Any ideas how can I troubleshoot this issue?

edit: It works after I restart my digitalocean's droplet

More info after edit:

Ubuntu 18.04 server.

Comment: Done. @K7AAY. Added extra info.